# C# EF Lambda select with function

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

Is it possible to add a function inside a lambda select statement?
This is totally wrong syntax, but it's for demonstration purpose.

```
var test = _context.SomeDatabaseTable
            .Select(c => new SomeViewModel
            {
                AssignedUsers = {
                    foreach (var item in c.AssignedToUserIDs.Split(';').ToList()) {

                        //SOME CODE

                    }
                }
            });
```

Anyone knows if its possible of i have to loop the results afterwards?

Comment: why cant you simple do outside

Comment: As far as I know this isn´t possible on EF as the code can´t be converted to valid SQL.

Comment: You can loop the answer afterwards with a result.Foreach(r => doSomething);

Comment: You are trying to do too many things at once. Remember, EF is an ORM - it loads data. If you try to use it for other things, you'll get horrible performance at best. Mixing up data access and viewmodels is *not* a good idea. ViewModels were created to add another layer of separation between model and view, not be used as DTOs. Write a query that loads the data you need, *then* map that data to viewmodels

Comment: Another bad idea is storing IDs as a CSV string instead of using proper relations in your EF model and database. That one is simply impossible to fix because the bug goes all the way down to the field. Create a many-to-many relation instead and let EF handle it. That's its job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you can't do that is because the `Select()` query doesn't actually execute your query against the database, so EntityFramework attempts to convert that C# code into SQL, which it obviously can't.

You can execute the query by calling `ToList()` before calling `Select()`.

```
var test = _context.SomeDatabaseTable
                   .ToList()
                   .Select(c => new SomeViewModel
                   {
                       AssignedUsers = c.AssignedToUserIDs.Split(';')
                   });
```

This has its own issues though, if you haven't filtered your query properly before executing `ToList()`, you will start coming across performance issues which gets worse as the size of your db grows.

What you're attempting with that `foreach` loop is also invalid. It shouldn't even compile so remove that and use what I've shown above, I assumed the AssignedUsers property was of type 'List', if you want to modify the individual elements that's been split, you can chain another `Select()` method to the end of `Split()`